# django-bootstrap5 and button alignment

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, bootstrap-5

I want to display a button next to a form instead of below:

This is how it looks:

[image]

should look like this:

[image]

corresponding code:

form:

```
class TheForm(forms.Form):
    var = forms.ChoiceField(choices = choices, label = "")
```

temp

```
late:

{% if TheForm %}
    <form method = "post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% bootstrap_form TheForm %}
        {% bootstrap_button button_type="submit" content="OK" %}
    </form>
 {% endif %}
```

EDIT:
Got it working, but the code only works with one input field:

[image]

I imagined it would look like this:

[image]

but the produced code looks weird too:

```
<form method="POST" action="/singleDevice">
    <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="...">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-9">
            <div class="col-12">
                <select name="env" class="form-select" id="id_env">
                    <option value="0">A</option>
                    <option value="3">NB</option>
                </select>
             </div>
             <div class="col-12">
                <label class="visually-hidden" for="id_Number">directly enter a number</label>
                <input type="text" name="Number" class="form-control" placeholder="directly enter a number" id="id_Number">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3"> 
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">OK</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try bootstrap Grid system,

template.html

```
{% if TheForm %}
    <form method = "post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="row"> <!-- creates a row of 12 parts -->
            <div class="col-lg-9"> <!-- Creates a column with width of 9 parts out of the above 12 parts -->
                {% bootstrap_form TheForm %}
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">  <!-- Creates a column with width of remaining 3 parts out of the above 12 parts -->
                {% bootstrap_button button_type="submit" content="OK" %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
 {% endif %}
```

**EDIT: CSS TO SET BUTTON AT THE END OF FORM**

```
<form method="POST" action="/singleDevice">
    <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="...">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-9">
            <div class="col-12">
                <select name="env" class="form-select" id="id_env">
                    <option value="0">PROD</option>
                    <option value="1">QA</option>
                    <option value="2">DEV</option>
                    <option value="3">NB</option>
                </select>
             </div>
             <div class="col-12">
                <label class="visually-hidden" for="id_Number">directly enter a number</label>
                <input type="text" name="Number" class="form-control" placeholder="directly enter a number" id="id_Number">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3"> 
            <button class="btn btn-primary form-submit-button" type="submit">OK</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**base.css:**

```
.form-submit-button{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 95%;  /* (approx) */
}
```

**CHANGES:** I have set a classname to the submit button and pushed the submit button to the bottom end of the y-axis using margin-top (percentage ensures that it stays below even on resizing)

Comment: This worked, but however, when using a form with two fields, the button now always stays on the first line.

Comment: please update the image and also mention where exactly you want the button to be displayed

Comment: just did that. you were just quicker.

Comment: does the number of input fields keep changing dynamically ? or is it just two fields

Comment: if you ask like this I tend to say dynamically. But for now it is two. Would be great to see the dynamically working solution.

Comment: well your code looks fine. you just have to tweak the CSS part a little bit... Just for easy visual try setting different background colors to both col div's ( col-9 and col-3 so that you can visualize tha partition) and then you will see try placing the button to the bottom end using any of  css positioning... Ill update one possible way of css part above

Comment: I see in the code `<div class="col-12">` these cols are being added - which is probably the problem.

Comment: no dont think so.. Try to visualize this... First you create a row of 12 parts... Then you divide that plane(row of 12 parts) into two planes of 9parts and 3 parts respectively... Noy you take the 9 part pane and and then again create two cols(col-12 means a row) fill size.. so the right plane is undisturbed in this entire process... So now just position the button wherever you want in the right pane.. .Sorry if this is confusing :o

Comment: This works perfectly, when I do it manually ... but also your code does not produce the same result, once `{% bootstrap_form FormName %}` is used, because of the extra `<div class="col-12">` inserted by `django-bootstrap5`.

Comment: Yes ... that is because you are using a bootstrap styled form.. But you can work around that too... from your browser console, You see the id's or Class of the form elements being rendered and you can tweak that CSS too as per your wish